# How a sound is played in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

simple question i asked myself yesterday, if an os is multitask, it will be able to play sound and do other stuff at the same time, because of task managing right ? But, why the sound is great and do not have any interference ?

thanks per avance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this is related to c++, but when you play sound on a computer, it consumes resources by entering CPU cycles. Sound is seemingly "great" because CPUs nowadays are much more capable, and the extra load has a negligible effect on system performance, and you don't have stutters due to depletion of resources.

If you are talking about signal interference, this is about circuit/PCB design, not about the OS or CPU scheduling.

Comment: Yeah, not really related to c++ but it's just about if i make a thread to play my music, it will sound great or not ?

Comment: Without knowing more about your system and the music format, I would say it will have minimal difference one way or the other. Even if you don't use multithread, when the code executes the line where you invoke (I use ALSA on Linux, for instance) the sound device. In my knowledge, the actual "playing" is detached from your program and enters the system ALSA daemon thread anyway.

Comment: Right ! it was just for me, i will use sfml so i don't care because sf::Music use it's own thread but i was just curious about how a computer manage sound

Comment: AFAICT this answer is wrong - the reason sound doesn't stutter is because there is a non-trivial amount of buffering in the actual audio hardware. The CPU with a few cycles hands out a big chunk of audio data. There's no CPU thread to play each individual sample; that too is handled by the audio hardware.

Comment: Okay !! so you confirm sound its a particular thing in an executable ?